# Git pull failing

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm unable to do a `git pull`. I am using `sourcetree`.

The error message is:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://*bitbucket_account_name*/path/to/repo.git/': Operation timed out after 300023 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received.

So I tried to pull for 5 minutes. I was able to pull earlier until this morning but am now getting a different, weird and incorrect behaviour.

Expected behavior:

1. After I stash and pull my working copy is clear till I make the next
   change on my local copy and save it.
2. `sourcetree` shows no more new commits to pull pending till other developers commit and push again.

Observed behavior:

1. After I stash and pull, all the changes due to the pull reflect as my working copy. So, I get a working copy of 27 files *as soon as* I pull. No conflicts.
2. I am shown just as many commits to pull pending immediately after I pull. So if I had 20 commits to pull, and then pulled, I am being shown 20 commits to pull again from the moment I pull onwards.

The pull was completed without any error shown, though.  I tried a hard reset as well as pulling using terminal instead of `sourcetree`. No good. How do I fix these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was happening because I had pushed when pulls were pending. I had to commit and push the working copy appearing automatically after the pull and it is now working fine.

Comment: You can accept it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Comment: my own answer? :-P

Comment: Yeah. But you need to accept it 48 hours later after your own answer is added (by the SO rule) :)