# Operation timed out after 300000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received on "git clone"

Tags: git, ubuntu

I'm using git on my Ubuntu 18.04 and when I try to clone a repository I got the next problem. The command don't work and get me back this error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myuser/myproject.git/': Operation timed out after 300000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

I already tried with other git repositories from other websites and got the same. I reinstalled git but no way. Thank you for your help and sorry for my English, I'm learning just now.

Comment: This looks related to networking issues rather than programming. I suggest you ask in Super User.

Comment: It could be the problem, but I have a good connection. I can do other git commands like push successfully.

Comment: I am blocked because of this beautiful error. I am unable to clone my repo to my Linux machine. I am trying this for several days. May be I will have to re-install the operating system, that will take lesser time I guess.

Comment: Is there really no solution? I am also blocked because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually related to a proxy issue.
Double-check:

```
env|grep -i proxy
git config -l | grep -i proxy
```

But that would not explain why push works, and clone does not.

If so, check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48540877/6309), and make sure you don't have other programs/IDE doing a push, while you are trying a pull/clone.

Comment: I am blocked because of this beautiful error. I am unable to clone my repo to my Linux machine. I am trying this for several days. May be I will have to re-install the operating system, that will take lesser time I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, couldn't really figure out the reason. but I solved by downgrading git to 2.21.2 (building it from source).

Comment: Was it also on Ubuntu? Did you try the latest 2.29.1?

Comment: I was on Pop-os-20.04, no I didn't try it, it was 2.27 that had the issues.

Comment: OK. you can upgrade Git thrpugh ppa or rebuild it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24847953/6309

Answer (score 0):

This is in the case if first answer does not work The latest version of git does not require to set proxy it directly uses system proxy settings .so just do these

```
unset HTTP_PROXY
unset HTTPS_PROXY
```

in some systems you may also have to do

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

and check other proxes with

```
prinenv | grep proxy
```

forethere , you can check your proxy with this :

```
git config --global --list
```